# python wand error "wand.resource.DestroyedResourceError: <wand.image.Image: (closed)> is destroyed already"

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf, wand

I am trying to run a script that will go through a specific folder and use Wand to create a .png file of every .pdf file that it finds in that folder.

```
from wand.image import Image
import os

pdf_dir = r"D:\Program Files\Python\Python36-32\tom's shitty programs\Downloads"

for x in os.listdir(pdf_dir):
    if x.endswith(".pdf"):
        pdf_path = pdf_dir + '\\' + x
        with Image(filename=pdf_path, resolution=300) as pdf:
            page_index = 0
            height = pdf.height
        with Image(width=pdf.width, height=len(pdf.sequence)*height) as png:
            for page in pdf.sequence:
                png.composite(page, 0, page_index * height)
                page_index += 1
            png.save(filename=pdf_path[:-3] + "png")
```

This returns the following errors:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python36-32\tom's shitty programs\venv\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 1799, in wand return self.resource

File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python36-32\tom's shitty programs\venv\lib\site-packages\wand\resource.py", line 151, in resource raise DestroyedResourceError(repr(self) + ' is destroyed already')

wand.resource.DestroyedResourceError:  is destroyed already

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):

File "D:/Program Files/Python/Python36-32/tom's shitty programs/wand_test.py", line 13, in  with Image(width=pdf.width, height=len(pdf.sequence)*height) as png:

File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python36-32\tom's shitty programs\venv\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 1817, in width return library.MagickGetImageWidth(self.wand)

File "D:\Program Files\Python\Python36-32\tom's shitty programs\venv\lib\site-packages\wand\image.py", line 1801, in wand raise ClosedImageError(repr(self) + ' is closed already')

wand.image.ClosedImageError:  is closed already

Any help is appreciated... thank you

Answer (score 1):

This is just some minor [`with ... as ..` context manager](http://book.pythontips.com/en/latest/context_managers.html) issues and/or typos. As the error message states, you are attempting to work with a variable (`pdf`) after the resources has already been closed. Double check the indentation.

```py
with Image(filename=pdf_path, resolution=300) as pdf:
    page_index = 0
    height = pdf.height
    with Image(width=pdf.width, height=len(pdf.sequence)*height) as png:
        for page in pdf.sequence:
            png.composite(page, 0, page_index * height)
            page_index += 1
        png.save(filename=pdf_path[:-3] + "png")
```

If you're using version 0.5.0 of Wand, then you might be able to take advantage of [`wand.image.Image.concat`](http://docs.wand-py.org/en/0.5.0/wand/image.html#wand.image.BaseImage.concat) method.

```py
with Image(filename=pdf_path, resolution=300) as pdf:
    pdf.concat(True)
    pdf.save(filename=pdf_path[:-3] + "png")
```